# Using full Kestrel server instead of the test server?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, integration-testing, kestrel-http-server, testserver

While using the test server from the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Testing` package with code like this

```
var webAppFactory = new WebApplicationFactory<Program>();
var httpClient = webAppFactory.CreateClient();
```

I noticed that this is not using a Kestrel server and therefore some things don't work like on a real Kestrel server, e.g. body size limits:

> warn: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Filters.RequestSizeLimitFilter[1]
> A request body size limit could not be applied. This server does not support the IHttpRequestBodySizeFeature.

So, how can I run a real Kestrel server during my integration tests?

Comment: _"how can I run a real Kestrel server during my integration tests?"_ - you shouldn't: the Testing Webserver is not actually a web-server at all: it doesn't listen on any TCP ports or accept "real" HTTP traffic - whereas if you _did_ try to use a "real" HTTP web-server with VS's Tests you will run into countless problems.

Comment: In a Integration test you can install/start your App and really call it.

Comment: @Dai well, but I need to test if my server side body size limit checks are fine and therefore I need a full Kestrel (and a test server for other tests, where the test server is enough)

Comment: In that case (if you _really need_ to test this) then you should put it in your E2E tests, not an Integration Test - because you're testing a _server configuration_ parameter (which presumably can differ between Production and Dev/Test/Staging?), so having an automated integration test (using ASP.NET Core's integration test features) is a low-value test, whereas if you're testing a known environment that is expected to have a request body size limit (i.e. your Production) then that's in the scope of an E2E test.